# Aborting pending / backlog of AJAX requests using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, backlog

I have the following script:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#input').keyup(function(){
        sendValue($(this).val());   

    }); 

});
function sendValue(str){
    $.post("ajax.php",{ sendValue: str },
    function(data){
        $('#display').html(data.returnValue);
    }, "json");

}
```

The script is used in an instant search type scenario (like Google), so it is sending quite a few select requests to the server as the user types in the textbox (although I already use pconnect so there are no repeated databse connections).

It is quite a large database and every keystroke is sent as an AJAX request, so it ends up with a massive backlog of pending requests. I'd like it to stop/cancel all previous requests (if they haven't been send back) every time it sends a new request.

I've looked at `xhr.abort()` but I'm pretty sure that will just stop any requests that haven't yet been sent (as opposed to telling the server to stop processing). This is probably OK, but I still don't know how to implement it in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use approach similar to this, in order to store the last request in some non-global scope:

```
function getSendValueFunction(){
    var lastRequest;

    return function(str){
        if (lastRequest){
            lastRequest.abort(); // abort pending request
        }
        // assign pending request, when created
        lastRequest = $.post("ajax.php",{ sendValue: str },
        function(data){
            lastRequest = null; // clear pending request
            $('#display').html(data.returnValue);
        }, "json");

    }
}

var sendValue = getSendValueFunction();
```

Just remember, that `getSendValueFunction` returns functions that have separate registers of last pending request. So this will make them have 2 different pending request, completely separated:

```
var sendValue1 = getSendValueFunction();
var sendValue2 = getSendValueFunction();
sendValue1('aaa');
sendValue2('bbb');
```